# Cufon jquery accordion problem

Tags: jquery, menu, accordion, cufon

I'm trying to add accordion menu on elements, which are styled with Cufon, in a website I'm making. But it doesn't work properly. And I guess that's because the elements are styled with Cufon. Because it works without Cufon. How can I solve this problem?

### javascript:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#accordion").accordion();
});
</script>
```

### html:

```
<div class="subMenu">
            <div>title</div>
            <div id="accordion">
                <h2><a href="javascript:void(0);">item x</a></h2>
                <div>xx</div>

                <h2><a href="javascript:void(0);">item y</a></h2>
                <div>yy</div>

                <h2><a href="javascript:void(0);">item z</a></h2>
                <div>zz</div>
            </div>
         </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute your javascript after cufon executes.

Comment: Topraam daha açıklayıcı yazabilir misin ?

Comment: Merhaba, cufon is changing your dom structure, so first determine if your jquery selector works. you can look at it from generated html by using firebug. If your selector works, than try to put a delay with settimeout function in javascript. and execute your javascript three seconds after loading page. $("#accordion").accordion(); if this works then cufon has a mechanism that you can be sure your javasript is executed after cufon is finished.

Comment: Load cufon after jquery as shown in number one [here] (https://github.com/sorccu/cufon/wiki/FAQ)